# Como posso separar os itens de um sharedPreferences em uma Array?

Tags: java, android, array, sharedpreferences

Estou com uma dúvida, fiz um checkbox em itens de uma listview que quando marcadas são armazenadas como SharedPreferences.
Então criei um botão (Favoritos) para acessar os itens marcados pelo checkbox, mas os itens marcados vão para o Favoritos eu criei novamente uma nova listview para receber os itens, mas vários itens vem somente com um item na listview Favoritos, gostaria de separa-los.

Segue meu código:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("arquivoPreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);

       String fraseR = String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getAll());


            // CRIANDO O ARRAY

            final String[] frasesFavoritoArray =
                    {
                            fraseR
                    };
```

Creio que o problema está justamente no Array que está recebendo todos os itens no 'fraseR', mas não saberia separa-los.

Existe alguma solução para isso?

Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque o seu código por esse:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("arquivoPreferencia", MODE_PRIVATE);
List<String> frasesFavoritoArray = new Arraylist<>();
Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPreferences.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {    
   frasesFavoritoArray.add(entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, Márcio.
Resolvido o problema!
A solução proposta acima resolveu o problema.
Tinha uma parte do meu código que tive que corrigir, Muito Obrigado!!!